# What is the keyboard shortcut to insert a comment during track changes in Word?

Tags: macos, ms-office

When I am editing a Word document using track changes it would be nice not to have to got to the mouse to insert a comment at the cursor (since this is most of what my editing consists of).

**What is the keyboard shortcut to insert a comment at the cursor in MS Word on a Mac when using track changes?**

I am running Word 14.2.5 and OS X 10.5.8

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Insert a comment
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>OPTION</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Turn track changes on or off
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

From [here](http://gezin.us/post/121789424/word-mac-keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 1):

They actually do post it: They won't let me post without 30 characters, otherwise this would just be the link:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/mac-word-help/word-keyboard-shortcuts-HA102929541.aspx

Comment: IMO this is the best answer, despite the critique, "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed."